# Calling C function in fortran where argument is a pointer

Tags: c, fortran

I have a C function that takes in an int pointer.

```
void setCoords(int *coords)
```

Where coords is an array.

In Fortran, I tried to call this function, using:

```
integer, dimension(10) :: coords
call setCoords(coords)
```

I receive a compilation error stating that the shape matching rules of the dummy and actual arguments were violated. Note that this code used to compile with no issues when I used GNU compilers. After switching over to Intel compilers, I get this issue.

Comment: Posting the   exact error would be useful.

Comment: For Intel Fortran, see the example in the documentation here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-19.0-developer-guide-and-reference-standard-fortran-and-c-interoperability

Comment: Welcome, please take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask].  You should show us more of your code, especially how the interface to the subroutine looks like, if there is one ([mcve]). Alao, always copy and paste the program output with the *exact* error message. It is *really important* so that others  with the same error can find your question. Do not just say *an error saying something*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an `interface` that declares the parameter as a `C_PTR`.  The Intel [Fortran 19.0 manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-19.0-developer-guide-and-reference-standard-fortran-and-c-interoperability) gives the following example of calling a C function with prototype

```
int C_Library_Function(void* sendbuf, int sendcount, int *recvcounts);
```

First, define a module such as:

```
module ftn_C_2
       interface
         integer (C_INT) function C_Library_Function &
         (sendbuf, sendcount, recvcounts) &
            BIND(C, name='C_Library_Function’)
            use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING 
            implicit none
            type (C_PTR), value :: sendbuf
            integer (C_INT), value :: sendcount
            type (C_PTR), value :: recvcounts
         end function C_Library_Function
       end interface
    end module ftn_C_2
```

Then, in the calling function, use it as follows:

```
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, only: C_INT, C_FLOAT, C_LOC
    use ftn_C_2
    ...
    real (C_FLOAT), target :: send(100)
    integer (C_INT) :: sendcount
    integer (C_INT), ALLOCATABLE, target :: recvcounts(100)
    ...
    ALLOCATE( recvcounts(100) )
    ...
    call C_Library_Function(C_LOC(send), sendcount, &
    C_LOC(recvcounts))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I was porting over a user-defined data type, like CircleClass? Would it then be             


CircleClass (C_CIRCLECLASS), value :: object

Comment: It is a C struct.

Comment: Anyway, no, that's not an intrinsic type the Fortran compiler would recognize. You would need to tell it the types of the members.

Comment: So if the C_Library_Function function returns a type 'CircleClass' , what would the "integer (C_INT) function C_Library_Function" part change to?

Comment: @Iamanon You would declare a `type, BIND(C) :: CircleClass` within the `interface` and declare its members.  See the second example on the manual page I linked.